# Saving characters typed on keyboard

Tags: keyboard, text

Is there any way I can save the characters are typed on my keyboard?
I want to know if it is possible in any way to save the characters that are typed on my keyboard by making changes in any file or anything else.

Comment: You want a keylogger? Otherwise text editors are quite good at saving characters pressed down :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Shibhansh Dohare - there is a way to do exactly as your asking!

It is called a "Hardware Keylogger"

Hardware keyloggers are used for keystroke logging, a method of capturing and recording computer users' keystrokes, including sensitive passwords. They can be implemented via BIOS-level firmware, or alternatively, via a device plugged inline between a computer keyboard and a computer. They log all keyboard activity to their internal memory.

You can purchase Hardware Keyloggers online, as well as physical stores that sell spy stuff.

Answer (score 1):

There is a out-of-the-box solution for this in Ubuntu. It is called `gedit`. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter

`gedit`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then type all the characters inside `gedit`. They will all be recorded. After you are done, save recorded characters `File > Save` under the menu.

Hope this helps

Comment: I waited for this one :)